# How do I make photoshop only use a certain color set?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I want to make it so that I can change an image so that it only uses the colors I have listed, and if it doesn't have it, it changes to the closest available color. Is that possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer was in using an indexed color mode :)

Comment: Yeah, and you can convert back to RGB when you're done, if you'd like to keep editing with full colour and alpha abilities.